# Run simple Java program in Docker

Tags: java, docker

I am new to Java and Docker, so this may be very simple.

The program reads user input and passes it to a function that does a dfs for broken links with a depth limit.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CrawlerTest {

    public static void main(String [ ] args)
    {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter full website url to crawl, starting with http://");
        String domain = reader.next();
        System.out.println("Enter max crawl depth: ");
        int maxDepth = reader.nextInt();
        reader.close();
        Crawler crawler = new Crawler();
        crawler.crawl(domain, maxDepth);
    }
}
```

and the Crawler class imports the following libraries

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Stack;
import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import javafx.util.Pair;
```

1. I exported a runnable jar file in eclipse
2. I created a Docker file with contents below:

```
 FROM openjdk:12-alpine  
 WORKDIR / ADD Test.jar Test.jar  
 EXPOSE 8080  
 CMD java -jar Test.jar
```

3. I built the docker image with `docker image build .`. This succeeds and I get docker image id
4. Next, I just run this image with docker run -it

I am prompted to enter user input, which I successfully do. Then on hitting Enter second time I see the following errors, which I don't see when just running jar file in console:
[image]

Comment: Apparently the JAR requires some eclipse specific libraries that do not exist within the Docker container. Have you considered to use a build file and use multi stage docker builds such that you build your JAR using docker as well?

Comment: With the `NoSuchElementException` from the `Scanner` is assume you're trying to read stdin, and I don't know if that's available in the container you start. I don't know why I have to assume either since you obviously have a Java program you could show us.

Comment: updated the question. I was able to get a bit further with *docker run -it <imageid>*

Comment: It's considered a bad move to update a question in a way that makes previously legitimate answers obsolete.

Comment: Thanks, noted, I tried to be considerate in my edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaFX was removed from default Java distribution starting from JDK11. It needs to be added explicitly via Java module system. That's why you are getting `NoClassDefFoundError` for the `Pair` class. Either change Java version prior to 11 or remove `Pair` class to resolve the issue. You can also [add](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx) the JavaFX module to your module path.

Comment: That did, thanks a lot! I went with replacing the Pair class.

Answer (score 2):

Add `--attach` to the `docker run` command.

Without `--attach`, there is no console for the Java program to use, so any use of `System.in` will fail.